# Running two blocking functions at once

Tags: python, twisted, scapy

I've been working on a network sniffing application, which I'm currently trying to make remotely runnable. I'm using twisted for the networking part of it. Essentially, I send a packet to the sniffer that tells it to start, then a different one when it should stop.

The problem that I've been running into is that both twisted's reactor.run() and scapy's sniff() function block, so it seems impossible to sniff and send the sniffed data at the same time. Is there some established way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/hellais/txscapy)? Looks very out of date, so I don't know if it actually works.

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite what I'm looking for. This uses scapy to construct packets, which doesn't block, and then sends them with twisted. I'm looking for a way to sniff and send packets at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You probably want one of the multiple thread management APIs, such as `twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread()`:

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.threads.html#deferToThread

You might use it like:

```
def runScapy():
    d = reactor.deferToThread(scapy.sniff)
    d.addCallback(doSomethingWithSniffResult)

reactor.callWhenRunning(runScapy)
reactor.run()
```

..although I'm not familiar with scapy and I don't know how the interface is actually used.